# Lightning for Outlook doesn't appear

Tags: lightning-for-outlook

We are in the process deploying Saleforce and trying to setup Lightning for Outlook.

**Setup:**

- Exchange 2016 Server CU7 (Version 15.1 (Build 1261.35)) -on premise (no link to an Office 365 account)
- The exchange organization is still hybrid with Exchange 2010 and 2016 server. The test users are off course on the 2016 servers.
- We have several email domain name used and the EWS URL domain doesn't match the email domain name for most users.
- Client computers : Windows 10 Pro with Office 2016 pro

**Issue:**

For the same user the Lightning add-in does appear in Outlook 2016 for Mac, but not on Outlook for Windows.

We were instructed by Salesforce support to use the [Lightning-for-Outlook-Debug-Tool](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Lightning-for-Outlook-Debug-Tool&type=1) and I setup it and it does appear in the Outlook for Windows, but I don't know how to use it to get debug information (see screenshot below)

UPDATE
the Debug Tool correctly appears in Outlook for Mac and displays:
[image]

While on Outlook for Windows it displays:

[image]

**Questions:**

- What can prevent the addin from appearing in Outlook for Windows ?
- what EWS request can I launch in the debug tool to see what's going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to perform all available Windows Update to have the plugin to appear.

Unfortunately we didn't manage yet to identify which specific update is required and Salesforce technical support was unable to answer us on this.